# How to assign EC2 instance to aws autoscaling group with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create a terraform script to assign a new autoscale group to our existing EC2 instance. I based my script using the following terraform documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html). I have a data method pulling the Ec2 instance by filters. Just stuck on how to assign the instance ID to the "aws_autoscaling_group". The docs do not provide a variable for this, however, on the GUI you can click on a running instance to assign it. What have you all done to help resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a lot of instances to do this for? Or could you just use Terraform to create the ASG and then manually attach the instances to the ASG so that the ASG will start to manage them (with Terraform managing the ASG)?

Comment: Its only for one instance, but I would like to have it all automated if possible.

Comment: Why does it need to be automated? Is this not a one off thing where you're taking an existing instance and trying to move it into a new ASG? In future I'd expect you to create and manage your instances directly through the ASG if this is how you want to manage this instance now.

Comment: I guess I was overthinking the whole proccess